# How to SWIG in VS2010?

Tags: c++, python, visual-studio-2010, swig

Hey Everybody,
    I'm trying to SWIG a multi file project that I made in VS2010 (c++) to python. I've managed to link the Python26.lib file, and have SWIG generating a wrapper .cpp file for my main .cpp file. I've set my code to build a .dll with the extension .pyd.

This is the .i file I have currently:

```
%module HiveGPS

%{
#include "ou_thread.h"
#include "HiveGPS.h"
%}


%include ou_thread.h
%include HiveGPS.h
```

And I've mangaed to get a .py and .pyc file. Now, from my understanding in order to run my .py file, I need to link it to my .pyd file, but when I try to use VS2010 to build my project with the settings I listed above, it complains about a Thread class I'm using:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: HiveGPS, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Build started 5/11/2011 1:41:30 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Release\HiveGPS.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  HiveGPS_wrap.cpp
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(57): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'm_strName'
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(57): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(57): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(64): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'getName'
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(64): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(64): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(64): warning C4183: 'getName': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(98): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'm_strName'
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(98): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(98): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(104): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'getName'
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(104): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(104): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(104): warning C4183: 'getName': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(115): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'msg'
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(115): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(115): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(118): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'getMessage'
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(118): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(118): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(118): warning C4183: 'getMessage': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(51): error C2011: 'openutils::Thread' : 'class' type redefinition
1>          c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(51) : see declaration of 'openutils::Thread'
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(93): error C2011: 'openutils::Mutex' : 'class' type redefinition
1>          c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(93) : see declaration of 'openutils::Mutex'
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(113): error C2011: 'openutils::ThreadException' : 'class' type redefinition
1>          c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(113) : see declaration of 'openutils::ThreadException'
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\HiveGPS.h(29): error C2504: 'openutils::Thread' : base class undefined
1>c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\HiveGPS.h(53): error C2079: 'HiveGPS::readWriteMutex' uses undefined class 'openutils::Mutex'
1>HiveGPS_wrap.cpp(3086): error C2027: use of undefined type 'openutils::Thread'
1>          c:\users\*\desktop\hivegps\hivegps\ou_thread.h(51) : see declaration of 'openutils::Thread'
1>HiveGPS_wrap.cpp(3086): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:02.10
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

All of these errors (minus the last one) are basically saying that the String class is implemented somehow, is it conflicting with Python's definition of the String class? The last error is complaining about the Thread class, could that be the same problem?

All of that said:
   Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong, or better yet, point me to a tutorial of how to do this for VS2010 (the SWIG site is for 2008).

And if that can't be done, can I link the .py file I have generated to the .dll file somehow?

Sorry for the long explanation but I'm kinda lost on this one so I decided to explain everything.

Comment: It could be anything.  SWIG supports quite a bit, but needs help with some constructs.  Without seeing the header files or how you are compiling the generated SWIG wrapper, it's hard to determine what is wrong.

Comment: If the string used is std::string, see http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html

Answer (score 11):

Ok, I'm using swig and VS2010 with no problems...

In your case, it looks more like you have problems with linking. Beyond the check of libraries, dont forget to check 32-64 bit libraries you are linking. Try to link all as x86 target as fail-safe. And don't use **AnyCpu**.

---

**How to use SWIG under VS2010.**

lets define you want to obtain mylib.py, so you created some SWIG interface files with mylib.i as "main" file. I assume that you already have a solution with project with your C++ classes there.

**(1)** First create C++ project for SWIG interface. Use Visual C++->Class library project which should create a C++ DLL stub. I put all .i files there. And  set visual studio to highlight .i as .h - it is handy.

**(1.1)** Add mylib_wrap.cxx file to the project (create empty file while swig hasn't generated one yet)

**(2)**
a) Press right button over the mylib.i, choose properties.
b) set ItemType as "Custom build tool".
In custom build step window:
c) Command line field should be something like:

```
echo In order to function correctly, please ensure the following environment variables are
correctly set: 
echo PYTHON_INCLUDE: %PYTHON_INCLUDE% 
echo PYTHON_LIB: %PYTHON_LIB% 
echo on 
C:\swig\swig.exe -c++ -python %(FullPath)
```

change C:\swig\swig.exe to your path to SWIG

d) In Outputs field:

```
$(InputName)_wrap.cxx
```

[image: Custom build window]

**(3)** Go to this project properties:

a) **C++ tab** -> **Additional Include Directories**
add $(PYTHON_INCLUDE); ...

c) **Linker** -> **Output File**
*Path-You-Needed*\_mylib.pyd

d) **Linker** -> **Enable Incremental Linking**
set as No (/INCREMENTAL:NO)

e) **Linker** -> **Input** -> **Additional Dependencies**
add $(PYTHON_LIB);...

f) **C/C++** -> **Precompiled Headers**:
Switch off precompiled headers, set **Not Using Precompiled Headers* and remove stdafx files after

g)  **General** tab. Just check that these are set:
Configuration type = Dynamic Library (.dll)
Character set = Use Unicode Character Set
Common Language Runtime Support = No Common Language Runtime Support

It compiles.

P.S. And dont forget to set  %PYTHON_INCLUDE%  and %PYTHON_LIB% variables in your system too.

Comment: should output .cxx file has to be included into project?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some #include is missing in the ou_thread.h.

Further more, the "'class' type redefinition" can indicate that you don't have something like

```
#ifndef __ou_thread_h__
#define __ou_thread_h__

// your stuff, classes, etc.

#endif
```

in your ou_thread.h

It's a guessing...