# How can I build this simple C++/SWIG/C# project in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, swig

I need help setting up a simple C++/C# SWIG project.  I am having a hard time putting together a C++ project that uses the SWIG bindings.  I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and the most recent version of SWIG.

My code is simply:

**cpp_file.h:**

```
#pragma once
class cpp_file
{
public:
    cpp_file(void);
    ~cpp_file(void);

    int times2(int arg);
};
```

**cpp_file.cpp**

```
#include "cpp_file.h"
cpp_file::cpp_file(void)
{
}
cpp_file::~cpp_file(void)
{
}
int cpp_file::times2(int arg)
{
return arg * 2;
}
```

And my SWIG interface file is:

**cpp_file.i**

```
/* cpp_file.i */
%module cpp_file
%{
/* Put header files here or function declarations like below */
extern int times2(int arg);
%}
extern int times2(int arg);
```

I can compile this project fine.  I then run the SWIG command to generate the wrapper:

```
swig -csharp "C:/pathToFile/cpp_file.i"
```

I don't know what to do at this point.  I can't find any tutorials or documentation that explains what to do in Visual Studio 2010.

When I add the *cpp_file_wrap.c* file that SWIG generates to my Visual Studio 2010 project and attempt to build the project, I get two linker errors.

1. error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
2. error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _times2

The first error message points to my dll file.  The second error points to some object file (*.obj).  The symbol that the error message mentions "_times2" is no where to be found in my project.

How can I move forward with my simple project?  Is there some tutorial or some documentation that explains this process step-by-step?  I can't find anything that involves C++ with SWIG, C#, Visual Studio 2010, and .Net v4.0.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Step-by-Step instructions to completely build in the VS2010 IDE:

1. Create a solution with two projects:

   - C# Console Application
   - C++ Win32 Console Application (Name=cpp, DLL, empty project).  If you choose a different name, don't use the name of a class in your project and update the **.i** file `%module` name to match.
2. Create a folder in the C# project called **Generated**.
3. Add your .cpp, .h, and .i file to the DLL with the modifications below.

   - Note the whole class has to be exported. Replace `<project>` with the name of the project.  There will be a preprocessor definition `<project>_EXPORTS` already defined for your DLL project (see Project, Properties, C++, Preprocessor).
   - The module name cannot match a class name in the module.
   - `%include <windows.i>` helps SWIG understand certain "Window-isms" like `__declspec`.

#### cpp_file.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef <project>_EXPORTS
#define <project>_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define <project>_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class <project>_API cpp_file
{
public:
    cpp_file(void);
    ~cpp_file(void);

    int times2(int arg);
};
```

#### cpp_file.i

```
%module cpp

%{
#include "cpp_file.h"
%}

%include <windows.i>
%include "cpp_file.h"
```

1. Select `cpp_file.i`, Properties, General, Item Type as **Custom Build Tool**.
2. Select **Apply** to create the Custom Build Tool property group.
3. In Custom Build Tool, General, Command Line enter:
   **swig -csharp -c++ -outdir** *GeneratedFolderPath* **cpp_file.i**
4. In Outputs, enter **cpp_file_wrap.cxx**, and click OK to close the dialog.
5. Right-click `cpp_file.i` and Compile.  This should create four files: three in the C# Generated folder and one in the C++ project.
6. Create a **Generated Files** filter in the C++ project and add **cpp_file_wrap.cxx** to it.
7. Add the three Generated files to the C# project's Generated folder.
8. Right-click the C# project and add the C++ project as a dependency.
9. In the C# project's Properties, Build tab, change the Output Path from `bin\Debug` to `..\Debug` or whatever the relative path to the C++ Project output directory is.  The .exe and .dll need to be in the same directory.
10. In the C# project's `Main`, add the lines:
    `var cpp = new cpp_file();`
    `Console.WriteLine(cpp.times2(5));`
11. Build the solution.
12. Run the C# project.

Good luck!  Let me know if you get it to work.  I can expand on anything unclear.

Comment: It worked!  Thank you Mark.  I had a little trouble making sure my output directory was correct (step #9).  I got an error saying that my DLL couldn't be loaded.  When I fixed my output directory, it worked.  Also, in the first step #3, in the third bullet point, I think you meant to type "%include <windows.i> helps SWIG".  The cpp_file.i has <windows.i> so it's not really a problem.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I've only used SWIG a small amount but it looks like you're trying to export a function named 
`times()` in your .i file which doesn't exist. You do have a `cpp_file::times()` method but that is not exported. You either need to define the `times()` function or export the entire `cpp_file` class via SWIG.

I would spend some time reading the [official SWIG documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Contents.html#Contents), particularly the [SWIG and C++](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus) section. There is also [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969173/how-to-swig-in-vs2010) which has some information related to SWIG and VS2010.