# Swig with MonoTouch/Xamarin.iOS TypeInitializationException/EntryPointNotFoundException

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xamarin.ios, swig

I'm trying to use SWIG to wrap unmanaged C++ into my Xamarin.iOS project.  I've successfully wrapped it into a C# project following this tutorial:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9816646/2494785

Once I try to incorporate MonoTouch, I always get run-time errors as soon as a call is made involving my C++ code.

I understand minor tweaks need to be made when using SWIG with Monotouch, but I must be missing something.  I was following Stephane's blog http://blog.reblochon.org/2013/01/c-bindings-for-monotouch-using-swig.html#more as a reference.

Differences between my C#/Monotouch projects:

## Monotouch

- swig -csharp -c++ -outdir *myPath* **-dllimport __Internal** cpp_file.i
- I then run [this](https://gist.github.com/banshee/7000449) ruby script (created by James Moore) on my cppPINVOKE.cs

  ```
  ARGF.each do |l|
     case l
     when /public delegate void Exception(Argument)?Delegate/
        puts "  [MonoTouch.MonoNativeFunctionWrapper]", l
     when /static void SetPendingArgument(Null|OutOfRange)?Exception/
        puts "  [MonoTouch.MonoPInvokeCallback (typeof (ExceptionArgumentDelegate))]", l
     when /static void SetPending.*Exception/
        puts "  [MonoTouch.MonoPInvokeCallback (typeof (ExceptionDelegate))]", l
     when /static string CreateString/
        puts "  [MonoTouch.MonoPInvokeCallback (typeof (SWIGStringDelegate))]", l
     else
        puts l
     end
  end
  ```

## C#

- swig -csharp -c++ -outdir *myPath* cpp_file.i

Here's the exception I get when I try to run my project:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the
>   type initializer for cppPINVOKE
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception
>   was thrown by the type initializer for cppPINVOKE --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the
>   type initializer for SWIGExceptionHelper --->
>   System.EntryPointNotFoundException: SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_cpp
>   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   cppPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper:SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_cpp
>   (cppPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,cppPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,cppPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,cppPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,cppPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,cppPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,cppPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,cppPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,cppPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,cppPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,cppPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate)
>   at cppPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper..cctor () [0x000ef] in
>   c:\Users\joshs\ Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\StackOverFlowSwigWithXamarin\StackOverFlowSwigWithXamarin\Generated\cppPINVOKE2.cs:121
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at cppPINVOKE..cctor () [0x00000] in c:\Users\joshs\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\StackOverFlowSwigWithXamarin\StackOverFlowSwigWithXamarin\Generated\cppPINVOKE2.cs:141
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at cpp_file..ctor () [0x00000] in c:\Users\joshs\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\StackOverFlowSwigWithXamarin\StackOverFlowSwigWithXamarin\Generated\cpp_file.cs:43
>   at StackOverFlowSwigWithXamarin.MyViewController.b__0
>   (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00001] in
>   c:\Users\joshs\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\StackOverFlowSwigWithXamarin\StackOverFlowSwigWithXamarin\MyViewController.cs:38
>   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIControlEventProxy.Activated () [0x00000] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIControl.cs:30    at
>   (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:
>   UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)   at
>   MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args,
>   System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName)
>   [0x0004c] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
>   at StackOverFlowSwigWithXamarin.Application.Main (System.String[]
>   args) [0x00001] in c:\Users\joshs\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\StackOverFlowSwigWithXamarin\StackOverFlowSwigWithXamarin\Main.cs:17
>   2013-10-31 14:45:48.261 StackOverFlowSwigWithXamarin[13645:21e03]
>   Unhandled managed exception: An exception was thrown by the type
>   initializer for cppPINVOKE (System.TypeInitializationException)   at
>   cpp_file..ctor () [0x00000] in c:\Users\joshs\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\StackOverFlowSwigWithXamarin\StackOverFlowSwigWithXamarin\Generated\cpp_file.cs:43
>   at StackOverFlowSwigWithXamarin.MyViewController.b__0
>   (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00001] in
>   c:\Users\joshs\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\StackOverFlowSwigWithXamarin\StackOverFlowSwigWithXamarin\MyViewController.cs:38
>   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIControlEventProxy.Activated () [0x00000] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIControl.cs:30    at
>   (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain
>   (int,string[],intptr,intptr)   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main
>   (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String
>   delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in /Developer/
>   MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38    at
>   StackOverFlowSwigWithXamarin.Application.Main (System.String[] args)
>   [0x00001] in c:\Users\joshs\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\StackOverFlowSwigWithXamarin\StackOverFlowSwigWithXamarin\Main.cs:17
>   mono-rt: Stacktrace:

## So why am I getting this exception and how can I fix it?

---

Edit (2013-11-1)
My (more/less) complete setup:

VS2012 StackOverFlowSwigWithXamarin.sln contains two projects

- cpp.vcxproj (C++ project)
- StackOverFlowSwigWithXamarin.csproj (Xamarin iOS project created from VS (i.e. No .xibs))

  - The Xamarin project was made in VS2012 File -> New -> Project... -> Visual C# -> iOS -> iPad -> HelloWorld Application

### cpp Project

cpp_file.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef cpp_EXPORTS
#define cpp_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define cpp_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class cpp_API cpp_file
{
public:
    cpp_file(void);
    ~cpp_file(void);

    int times2(int arg);
};
```

cpp_file.cpp

```
#include "cpp_file.h"
cpp_file::cpp_file(void)
{
}
cpp_file::~cpp_file(void)
{
}
int cpp_file::times2(int arg)
{
    return arg * 2;
}
```

cpp_file.i

```
%module cpp

%{
#include "cpp_file.h"
%}

%include <windows.i>
%include "cpp_file.h"
```

The cpp_file.i file is set as a **custom build** option within VS2012.  It runs the command

> swig -csharp -c++ -outdir "$(SolutionDir)StackOverFlowSwigWithXamarin\Generated" cpp_file.i

The **outputs** from the **custom build tool** is specified as:

> cpp_file_wrap.cxx

....but I never use this file, I have no idea what it's there for?

Building my cpp Project produces the following files:

- cpp_file_wrap.cxx
- cpp.cs
- cpp_file.cs
- cppPINVOKE.cs

Afterwards, I run my ruby script to create a new file I named **cppPINVOKE2.cs**

### StackOverFlowSwigWithXamarin Project

AssemblyInfo.cs

I noticed Stephane mentioned to add `[assembly: LinkWith(....)`, but I did not, because I never created a .lib/.a

The autogenerated are added to my project:

- cpp.cs
- cpp_file.cs
- cppPINVOKE2.cs  (from the ruby script, mentioned above)

AppDelegate.cs, Main.cs

I made no changes to the default VS2012 -> iPad HelloWorldApplication

MyViewController.cs

I added one line to the default HelloWorldApplication.  When the user presses the button on the screen, it tries to instantiate a `cpp_file()`.

## My Concerns

- I never touch the .cxx file.  Why is it there? (Maybe that's part of my problem)
- From Stephane's blog, he recommends to add `[assembly: Linkwith(...)]` to my assemblyInfo.cs.  I never created a library, should I have?  If so, of what?

Comment: you might have to share a bit more, like the project files

Comment: I added quite a bit about my setup, as stated in my edit, I'm wondering if my problem is part of not using the autogenerated .cxx file and/or never creating some sort of library.

Comment: yeah, you should create a library from your objective-cpp project generated. that's a crucial part of the process

Comment: Excuse me of my lack of understanding, but do you add the C++ header files, the generated .mm file, and then custom make an Obj-C header? ...to the Obj-C static library, or is adding the C++ headers and .mm file all that is required to build the .a static library?