# Getting Started with SWIG and Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, swig

I'm trying to create my first SWIG python DLL with Visual Studio 2010, using an example I downloaded from swig,org.  I'm running Windows professional 64-bit.  I downloaded swigwin-2.0.7 and unzipped it. I've followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969173/how-to-swig-in-vs2010) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693047/how-to-create-a-dll-with-swig-from-visual-studio-2010) and in both cases, the wrap file gets built, but the project build fails.  The linker complains about 56 unresolved external symbols, all with names something like __imp__PyBytes_AsStringAndSize or __imp__PyExc_RuntimeError.

I've tried this using my python 2.7 installation as well as my python 3.2 installation, with similar results.  Do I have to build swig from the source for my platform?  I've spent the last 6 hours or so on this, and I'm nonplussed.

Comment: What example did you download from swig.org?  Common errors are providing the wrong path to the Python library or mixing 32- and 64-bit Pythons and extensions, but those give different errors that what you are seeing.  Did you follow the instructions exactly?  (I wrote the second set you referenced.)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The example I downloaded was the one called simple.  I certainly tried to follow the instructions exactly.  The paths to the libraries are correct.  I'm sure this is so, because in one of my iterations, I mistyped the library name, and the linker complained, but I'm not getting that error message now.

Answer (score 3):

Following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693047/how-to-create-a-dll-with-swig-from-visual-studio-2010), using the `simple` Python example from SWIG, Windows 7 64-bit and Python 2.7 32-bit, I did not see the OP's specific errors.  I saw:

```
1>example_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl gcd(int,int)" (?gcd@@YAHHH@Z) referenced in function __wrap_gcd
1>example_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "double Foo" (?Foo@@3NA)
```

Two changes had to be made due to the `simple` example being C source instead of C++:

1. Do not use the `-c++` switch on the `swig` command line (step 13 of the instructions).
2. The generated file is now `example_wrap.c` not `example_wrap.cxx` (referred to in steps 14 and 19 of the instructions).

Alternatively, just rename `example.c` to `example.cpp` in this case before following the instructions and they should work as is.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the follow-up.  I remote desktop'ed to my office machine, which has 32-bit python, and did the same thing as you, with the same results as you got.  I then tried building 64-bit SWIG from the sources on my home machine, but I still got all the same unresolved symbols.  Perhaps SWIG doesn't support 64-bit python yet?

Comment: I tested with 32-bit Python 3.2 and 64-bit Python 3.3b2 as well.  3.3b2 had a problem with the generated example.py proxy, but the _example.pyd worked fine.

Comment: clarification...are you building SWIG from sources?  I used the 2.0.7 binary downloaded from swig.org in all cases.

Comment: Originally, I used the binary downloaded from swig.org on both my office machine and my home machine.  After I had success on the office machine, I thought that perhaps I had to compile a 64-bit version of SWIG for my machine, since the only difference I could see was that I was using 32-bit python at work and 64-bit python at home.  I just tried installing SIP instead on my home machine.  I couldn't get NMAKE to work, so I tried with MinGW and I got similar linker errors: all kinds of unresolved symbols whose names start with _imp__.  This was with python 3.2.  I didn't bother with 2.7

Comment: SWIG doesn't need to be 64-bit.  The 32-bit binary in the `swigwin` distribution is all you need.